# Trigger: after updating account - by anonymous user?

Tags: users, rules

I have created an action sending me an e-mail if a user account has been changed/updated.
The e-mail contains tokens of the original user fields and the new entries for comparison.

Since these data could be changed by anyone with user management rights I'm also interested who made the changes and thus check for [current-user:name]

How can it be that this trigger fires when the change (or actually no visible change for me) has been made by "Anonymous"?

Wouldn't it be either the user himself/herself or a user with account rights to trigger this event? And yes, my Anonymous role has no user permissions set; I've checked this.

I was wondering if there is any other module triggering this event? Do you have any pointers what's going on here?

Comment: Try installing rules module. It has several conditions related to user account also. It might satisfy your function. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, for your comment - I know about the rules module. But the core Trigger module works, it's not functionality that is the issue, more the security concern I have: How can an anonymous user trigger a change account event?

Comment: have you tried to edit the user profile as an anon user? If the anon user has absolutely no permission to do so then it's most likely an error with token replacement.

Comment: If I try to edit the user which originally triggered the e-mail (listing the user as anonymous) - I get the expected "Access denied" page - so direct access to the edit page is not possible. I wonder if there's another process calling the user_save() procedure? Or is hook_user_update() the trigger?

Comment: Which version of Drupal is this about? I'm pretty sure it's D6, not (yet) D7. And I don't want to "guess" about the question before answering it ...

Comment: Pierre, not sure how you stumbled over this rather old discussion - but to clarify your question - this is in D7. However, I haven't noticed these triggers being fired by anonymous any more over the past months - so maybe one of the drupal core updates, or module updates has "fixed" this behavior.